# VBS / LIST of files with dates to EXCEL

Tags: excel, batch-file, vbscript

I'm currently looking for the way of get file information (DATE) and by using VBS place it to Excel report.

Currently bu using this VB Script I can get list of file names which used in current job and in

```
addCell = 7
for each myFile in fso.GetFolder(var1&"\BACKUP").Files
if fso.GetExtensionName(myFile) = "txt" then
    ws.Cells(addCell,1).Value = myFile.Path
    addCell=addCell+1
end if
next
```

But I need the same list with **DATE** when file was created/modified.

As well I though about using BAT/CMD to create a list of files, by using this code:

```
dir *.txt /o > test.txt
findstr /r /c:"^[0-9]" test.txt > list.txt
```

and then place this information to excel,

**Ideally** I need this line (made by CMD code) and place it to excel in specific cell.

```
15/09/2017  15:51            27,723 SAMPLE FILE.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `myFile.DateLastModified`. This should give you the modified date

Comment: Thank you, beautiful and simple solution -  myFile.Path & " | " &myFile.DateLastModified

Comment: No worries. If it helped, please don't forget to accept the answer